# Ubuntu Core NUC installation

Tags: system-installation, intel, ubuntu-core, intel-nuc

I am new to ubuntu core. 
I am following the instructions at 
https://developer.ubuntu.com/core/get-started/intel-nuc
in order to install ubuntu core on an intel nuc.

The procedure goes smooth (ie. no error messages) until reboot (first boot) but then it only boots the OS on the system disk, it won't boot ubuntu core and it won't present an option to select it, so it seems I am missing something in the instructions...

thanks for any guidence

best regards

jonas

Answer (score 1):

If you don't have a NUC with mmc you probably need to use:

> xzcat /media/ubuntu//ubuntu-core-16-amd64.img.xz | sudo dd of=/dev/**sda** bs=32M status=progress; sync

to write the image. (see [Ubuntu Core for non eMMC Intel NUCs](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1084599/ubuntu-core-for-non-emmc-intel-nucs))

This worked for me.