# Ubuntu Core for non eMMC Intel NUCs

Tags: ubuntu-core, intel-nuc

Is there any method to install Ubuntu Core onto an Intel NUC without eMMC ?

I have a bunch of older NUCs that don't have the eMMC storage; I'd like to install core on the hard disk, is that documented or an option?

Thanks

J.

Comment: It shouldn't be that different.

Comment: it's very much different hence I asked the question.

Comment: How different, really? What makes the difference is the hardware architecture defined by the CPU (and motherboard's chipset) and certainly ARM boots in a very different way than x86, x86_64. But Intel NUCs are x86_64 and UEFI so the requirements should be the same regardless of the type of the storage medium, a SATA HDD, a SATA SSD, a mSATA, a M.2 SATA or NVMe, SD, microSD or eMMC. It's just the **name** of the device that changes. https://www.ubuntu.com/download/iot/intel-nuc , same instructions but instead of `mmcblk` the drive will be `sda` (probably).

Comment: Cool, so you've done this yourself and can confirm it works without any deviation from changing the output device?

Comment: No, I didn't and and I won't. It just happens that I know a few things that apparently you don't. I suggest you actually test it and if you have an issue then ask about it specifically instead of posting a vague question that stems from the ignorance of basic principles of hardware, OSes, boot process and bootloaders.

Answer (score 0):

I actually need to confirm that writing the ubuntu core image to disk (a brand new one, there was no tolerance for an older one I initially tried) worked, same instructions, advised to wipe the disk using disk tools prior to the dd.

Thanks again to GabrielaGarcia, I do appreciate the answer but would like to remind you I asked an open question and really didn't deserve to be to rudely treated. I don't need to validate my *nix experience but would ask that your less rude and hostile in future comments or replies. My own initial comment was equally (if not more so) rude and with the benefit of hindsight appreciate neither was helpful or valid.

Have a nice day :)